# ¿Como puedo obtener un solo registro de una base de datos?

Tags: mysql, php7

```
`CREATE TABLE `reportes_mensuales` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `concepto` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ventas` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `costo` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `utilidades` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desde` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `hasta` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Volcado de datos para la tabla `reportes_mensuales`

```
INSERT INTO `reportes_mensuales` (`Id`, `concepto`, `ventas`, `costo`, `utilidades`, `desde`, `hasta`) VALUES
(40, 'Renta local', 890, 0, 890, '2020-02-01', '2020-02-29'),
(43, 'Ritmos latinos', 34, 5, 29, '2020-02-13', '2020-02-20'),
(53, 'Ritmos latinos', 34, 5, 29, '2020-02-01', '2020-02-29'),
(54, 'Renta local', 890, 0, 890, '2020-02-01', '2020-02-29'),
(55, 'Ritmos latinos', 34, 5, 29, '2020-02-08', '2020-02-19'),
(56, 'Ritmos latinos', 34, 5, 29, '2020-02-01', '2020-03-31'),
(57, 'Renta local', 890, 0, 890, '2020-02-01', '2020-03-31');
```

`[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]¿Como puedo obtener un solo registro de una base de datos con el mismo concepto registrado muchas veces obteniendo los totales y las fechas de inserción en un solo registro? para posicionar los totales según su fecha

Comment: No se entiende bien la pregunta. Cual es tu problema?

Comment: tengo una tabla con muchos conceptos que se repiten pero cada uno trae un total y una fecha y lo que quiero es traer todos los conceptos pero una unica vez que no se repitan pero que me muestre todos los totales y sus fechas de cada uno

Comment: como son los atributos de la tabla? podrias mostrarmelos?

Comment: podrias poner un ejemplo de salida  osea el resultado final de la consulta

Comment: Si no entendí mal necesitas una consulta de agrupación, investiga..

Comment: Según entiendo de esa salida quieres una columna por mes ¿ es correcto ? Si es así la fila con ID = 57 cuyo rango de fechas incluye varios meses, ¿ cómo debería interpretarse ? de cara a calcular los totales, ¿ se usa la fecha inicial o la final ?